# argparse not getting triggered

Tags: python, argparse

I'm trying to use the Python `argparse` module to check argument parameters:

```
import argparse
if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Example with non-optional arguments')

    parser.add_argument('count', action="store", type=int)
    parser.add_argument('units', action="store")

    print 'test'
```

When I run the script (`python test.py some inches`), it just prints the output `'test'` but the `argparse` module is not being triggered.

Comment: Oh, for... you never actually `parse_args`!

Answer (score 3):

You need to actually call it!

```
import argparse
if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Example with non-optional arguments')

    parser.add_argument('count', action="store", type=int)
    parser.add_argument('units', action="store")

    args = parser.parse_args()
    print args
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to parse the args for this to work. You either need to call `parser.parse_args()` or `parser.parse_known_args()`. More info can be found here:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.parse_args